# Indução de tipo para qualquer tipo de objeto

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, tipagem, parâmetros, indução-de-tipo

Estou querendo fazer com que um método de uma determinada classe aceite um objeto como parâmetro. Porém este objeto poderia ser de qualquer tipo. Exemplo:

```
class classeExemplo
{
    public function meuMetodo(Object $objeto)
    {
        // Seguiria aqui o bloco de código
    }
}

// Instanciando meus objetos
$produto = new Produto();
$usuario = new Usuario();

/* alimentaria meus objetos com suas respectivas informações */

// Instaciando minha classe que tem o método que recebe qualquer tipo de Objeto
$exemplo = new classeExemplo();

// Chamando o método passando objetos diferentes
$exemplo->meuMetodo($produto);
$exemplo->meuMetodo($usuario);
```

Isso, obviamente, não funciona. Alguém já se encontrou numa situação parecida? Como poderia contornar e de alguma forma fazer isso funcionar?

Comment: Já tentou usar uma classe abstrata encapsulando as demais? Ou precisa realmente ser qualquer tipo de objeto (inclusive de classes do próprio PHP)?

Comment: Não necessariamente as classes do próprio PHP, até porquê não analisei a este ponto, apenas as classes que criei mesmo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP é uma linguagem dinâmica. O normal dela é aceitar qualquer tipo, então basta não especificar tipo algum que será aceito:

```
class Produto{}
class Usuario {}
class classeExemplo
{
    public function meuMetodo($objeto) //<======== mudei aqui
    {
        // Seguiria aqui o bloco de código
    }
}

// Instanciando meus objetos
$produto = new Produto();
$usuario = new Usuario();

/* alimentaria meus objetos com suas respectivas informações */

// Instaciando minha classe que tem o método que recebe qualquer tipo de Objeto
$exemplo = new classeExemplo();

// Chamando o método passando objetos diferentes
$exemplo->meuMetodo($produto);
$exemplo->meuMetodo($usuario);
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/9bjBNm). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/dkktqcrl-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Function/Dynamic.php).

Answer (score 2):

Embora o que você esteja tentando não faça sentido (em nenhuma linguagem), abaixo é o mais próximo que você pode chegar:

```
class classeExemplo
{
    public function meuMetodo($objeto)
    {
        if (!is_object($objeto)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("Not an object!");            
        }

        print "ok\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta @felipsmartins. Porém não entendi porque não faz sentido querer induzir o tipo de dado no parâmetro, assim como fazemos com array. E o "(em nenhuma linguagem)", - se não me engano - no C# podemos induzir com que o parâmetro seja objeto com "... (Object $nomeObjeto){}"

Answer (score 1):

Atualmente não é possível definir tipos, porque o *PHP* por norma aceita qualquer tipo, mas adiconando o prefixo `Object` ao argumento, não estás propriamente a declarar o tipo para esse argumento, estás a declarar a instância à qual esse objecto deve pertencer.

```
<?php
class Teste
{
    public function show(Object $arg)
    {   
        return $arg;
    }
}
class Object {}
$objecto = (object) 'Teste';
// $objecto = new stdClass();

$teste = new Teste();
var_dump($teste->show(new Object)); # funciona (instancia de Object)
var_dump($teste->show($objecto)); # não funciona (instancia de stdClass)

?>
```

Para resolver isto basta que não atribuas um prefixo ao argumento em questão, e vai tudo funcionar as mil maravilhas.

```
<?php
...
public function show($arg)
        {   
            return $arg;
        }
...
?>
```

Mas se quiseres realmente definir um tipo específico para aquele argumento, ou um requisito para aquele determinado argumento, deves então trabalhar esse argumento de modo a criar essa regra.

Um outro exemplo seria este:

```
<?php

class Teste
{
    public function show($object=null)
    {
        if(!empty($object) && gettype($object) === 'object'){
            if(!($object instanceof stdClass)){
                return  "Retorno: \"{$object}\" é um objecto <br/>";
            }
            throw new Exception('é um objecto, mas não pode ser retornado como string');
        }
        throw new Exception("\"{$object}\" é " . gettype($object));
    }
}
class Object
{
    protected $nome;
    public function __construct($nome=null){
        $this->nome = $nome;
    }
    public function __toString(){
        if(!empty($this->nome)){
            return $this->nome;
        }
        return 'default';
    }
}

$teste = new Teste();
try{
    // print $teste->show(new stdClass());
    print $teste->show(new Object('LMAO'));
    // print $teste->show(new Object());
    // print $teste->show(1);
    // print $teste->show('teste');
    // print $teste->show(0.01);
} catch (Exception $e){
    print 'Excepção: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Simplesmente lança uma excepção caso a instância não for um objecto, ou caso este seja uma instância de `stdClass`.

Atualmente é possível passar argumentos por referência, e também espeficiar tipos de retornos para funções, se quiseres saber mais, podes seguir este [link](http://php.net/manual/en/langref.php) e navegar pelas categorias ***"Funcions"*** e ***"Clases and Objects"***. Claro, se procurares ainda mais, podes ainda encontrar outras boas sugestões, lá isso é o que não falta.

Answer (score 0):

Além dos métodos apresentados nas outras respostas, você pode criar uma classe englobando as demais que deseja passar neste parâmetro:

**Código:**

```
abstract class FooBar {
   public $name;
}

class Foo extends FooBar {
   public $name = "Foo";
}

class Bar extends FooBar {
   public $name = "Bar";
}

class Outra{
   public $name = "Outra";
}

class Teste {
   public function testar(FooBar $obj){
      echo $obj->name;
   }
}


$teste = new Teste();

$foo = new Foo();
$bar = new Bar();

$out = new Outra();

$teste->testar($foo);
echo PHP_EOL;
$teste->testar($bar);
echo PHP_EOL;
$teste->testar($out);
```

**Saída:**

```
Foo
Bar
<br />
<b>Catchable fatal error</b>:  Argument 1 passed to Teste::testar() must be an instance of FooBar, instance of Outra given, called in [...][...] on line 37 and defined in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>20</b><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

Essa técnica à qual você se refere se chama [overloading](http://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/method-overloading/). Esse conceito não existe em PHP. Se você tentar definir dois métodos com o mesmo nome porém com argumentos diferentes, terá um erro de sintaxe.

O que dá pra fazer é o seguinte:

```
public function meuMetodo($argumento)
{
    if ($argumento instanceof Produto) {
        // ...
    }
    elseif ($argumento instanceof Usuario) {
        // ...
    }
    else {
        throw new \Exception('Tipo de argumento inválido.');
    }
}
```

Também dá pra usar um bloco `switch`:

```
public function meuMetodo($object argumento)
{
    switch(get_class($argumento)) {
        case 'Produto':
            // ...
            break;
        case 'Usuario':
            // ...
            break;
        default:
            throw new \Exception('Tipo de argumento inválido.');
}
```